# Correct way to free arrays defined in structure

Tags: c

In C code I have a next structure:

```
typedef struct foo_s {
   int var_int;
   int arr_int[20];
}foo;
```

In particular stage I define a *foo* pointer:

```
foo* struct_var = (foo*)malloc(sizeof(foo));
```

In memory clear stage I have

`free(stuct_var)`

The question: Should I before the last statement explosively free array as

```
free(stuct_var->arr_int)
```

?

Comment: You can't free an array like that.  The array only exists as part of the struct that you allocated.  You either free the structure as a whole, or you free none of it.  The only pointers you can ever pass to `free` are ones that were returned directly by `malloc`, `realloc`, etc.  In this example, `struct_var` is the only pointer returned by malloc, to `struct_var` is the only pointer you can pass to `free`.

Comment: No. No. No. No.

Comment: You can only free what you (m/c/re)alloc'ed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `arr_int[20]` is a part of struct, you don't need to free it respectively. That is what are allocated by `malloc/calloc/realloc` they need to be cleaned up to avoid memory leak issue. Anyway if you make the inner array dynamic, then you will have to free it.

```
typedef struct foo_s {
   int var_int;
   int* arr_int;
}foo;

foo* struct_var = (foo*)malloc(sizeof(foo));
struct_var->arr_int = (int*)malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
```